# Rspec Rails 4.2.5 Request test pass with basic http auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

The setup is the following. For each http request the manager sends his credentials in the header(name,pw). These get checked against the entries in the db and if they succeed return the desired user object. How is it possible to implement basic http_auth in the request tests? I would like to add only the password and username and test the return value? Which is the goal of request tests,right? I tried the following without much success:

I created an AuthHelper module in `spec/support/auth_helper.rb` with

```
module AuthHelper
  def http_login
    user = 'test'
    pw = 'test'
    request.ENV['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] =ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(user,pw)
   end  
end
```

and use it in the `requests/api/user_spec.rb`    as follows

```
include AuthHelper
 describe "User API get 1 user object" do     
      before(:each) do
               http_login 
       end
```

but i receive this error message. How can i fix this and enable my tests to pass http_auth? I read lot of similar topis and questions also here but 
they apply mostly to older versions of rspec and rails and are not applying to my case

Thanks in advance!

```
Failure/Error: request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(user,pw)

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass# ./spec/support

 # ./spec/support/auth_helper.rb:5:in `http_login'
 # ./spec/requests/api/user_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Update**

I moved the header generation inside a request. I looked up the Auth verb, so i think the assignment should work. I tested the ActionController call in rails console and received a string. I suppose this is also correct.My whole test now looks like this:

```
describe "User API get 1 user object", type: :request do  
      it 'Get sends back one User object ' do             
              headers = {   
                            "AUTHORIZATION" =>ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials("test","test")
   #                        "AUTHORIZATION" =>ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials("test","test")
              }
              FactoryGirl.create(:user)
              get "/api/1/user", headers
              #json = JSON.parse(response.body)
              expect(response).to be_success
      #       expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
      end     
  end
```

receiving the following error:

which incudles the line `@buf=["HTTP Basic: Access denied.\n"]` so access is still denied.

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to be_success
   expected `#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x000000070d1d38 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x000000070d1c98>, @stream=#<ActionDispatch::Response::Buffer:0x000000070d1c48 @response=#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x000000070d1d38 ...>, 
 @buf=["HTTP Basic: Access denied.\n"], @closed=false>, @header={"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "WWW-Authenticate"=>"Basic realm=\"Application\"", "Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8", "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache", "X-Request-Id"=>"9c27d4e9-84c0-4ef3-82ed-cccfb19876a0", "X-Runtime"=>"0.134230", "Content-Length"=>"27"}, @status=401, @sending_file=false, @blank=false, 
@cv=#<MonitorMixin::ConditionVariable:0x000000070d1bf8 @monitor=#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x000000070d1d38 ...>, @cond=#<Thread::ConditionVariable:0x000000070d1bd0>>, @committed=false, @sending=false, @sent=false, @content_type=#<Mime::Type:0x00000002af78f8 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html">, @charset="utf-8", @cache_control={:no_cache=>true}, @etag=nil>.success?` 
to return true, got false
```

**SOLUTION**
This test is not polished (yet) but at least it passes now.

```
describe "User API get 1 user object", type: :request do  
    it 'Get sends back one User object ' do             
        @env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(user,pw)
              FactoryGirl.create(:user)

        get "/api/1/user", {}, @env

        JSON.parse(response.body)
        expect(response).to be_success
        expect(response.status).to eq 200
    end     
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the error carefully: `` undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass `` means `request` is nil. Are you trying to set the header *before* a test while you are defining the request later on *in* the test?

You might want to look at the documentation [for an example](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec#requesting-a-json-response) on how to set headers.

If you're still stuck, post one of your tests as well.

Comment: Nice! Definitely that header setting was a bit weird.  Yes i think it is better to define the headers inside the requests. I changed the setting of the http auth but i m still stuck. Still access is denied and i cant figure out why. I update my question. Thank you!

Comment: You can use a [let block](http://betterspecs.org/#let) to share the headers across tests to keep it DRY ;) Also, in your updated code you do not seem to be passing the headers variable as an argument to the get method? That would explain why access is still denied. An upvote or marking my answer as accepted is welcome of course :)

Comment: Thanks for the let block link. I ll dry it up asa i make it run. Yeah my eyes are almost squared right now. I really overlooked the pass the header to the request. (; but still it wont succeed. I still get the error access denied ....

Comment: It seems that something is wrong with your controller code then. Try the pry-byebug gem and use `binding.pry` to drop into a debugger on your console at various parts of the relevant controller code to find out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspicious:

```
request.ENV['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] =ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(user,pw)
```

Are you sure that `"ENV"` should be capitalized? I think it should be written like `"env"`.

Comment: Oh yeah i originally had it written in lower case letters, but someone suggested to try it capitalized. But with ways i get the same error message either with `request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` or `request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`

Comment: Have you tried adding `infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` to rails_helper file's config section?